# I'm trying to find the average, min and max of speed for every 100m of distance covered

Tags: python

I have written the following code to input distance, speed and time and to return the average, min and max speed for every 100m covered. The code works once and on the second run, I get the error shown at the bottom.

```
sparray=[]
lasttime=0
newtime=0
lastdist=0
newdist=0
i=1
while 1:
    dist=float(input("distance"))
    speed = float(input("speed"))
    sparray.append(speed)
    print(sparray)
    time = float(input("time"))

    if (dist >= 100 * i):
        newtime = time
        newdist = dist
        kmtime = newtime - lasttime
        kmdist = newdist - lastdist
        avg = kmdist / kmtime
        print("AVG: ", avg)
        maxi = max(sparray)
        mini = min(sparray)
        print("MAX: ", maxi)
        print("MIN: ", mini)
        sparray = []
        i = i + 1
        lastdist = dist
        lasttime = time
        avg=0
        max=0
        min=0
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Mahe.000/PycharmProjects/serialgraph/venv/test.py", line 21,
>   in 
>       maxi = max(sparray) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: At the end of your loop you are overwriting the `max` and `min` functions with `0`.

Comment: why do you initializing max=0 and min=0 everytime, i think it doesn't need,if you want    maximum among sparray , just simply call max(sparray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared/are using max and min variables in your code. They override max and min functions.

Here

```
max=0
min=0
```

And when you call `max()` python tries to apply your call to the int variable and you get the error you have reported.

Solution: use different names for `max` and `min` variables.

I've noticed that you are not using `max` and `min` variables in your code, except on initializing them to `0`.

Just remove this part of code in this case:

```
max=0
min=0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, even if it was so silly. Appreciate it.

Comment: @dkr Glad I helped you :)